Why is swiper made using swiper.js only swiping part a slide at a time?
I have a website made for mobile with a swiper initialized with swiper.js. I made sure to make it as the documentation says. However, the library enforces some styling on the swiper. To stop it changing my slides' size and background, I made some CSS attributes important.
This is probably the reason for my problem; not only do the first two slides not appear, the slider gets stuck at random points in between the slides. I don't want to have to change my entire CSS and I'm sure it's possible to make it work.
This is how the swiper glitches:

Here is the html code for the swiper:
<div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            
                <div class="person swiper-slide">
                    <img src="ioana.JPG"/>
                    <p>Ioana</p>
                    <p class="yellow">President</p>
                </div>

                <div class="person swiper-slide">
                    <img src="iarina.JPG"/>
                    <p>Iarina</p>
                    <p class="yellow">President</p>
                </div>
    
                <div class="person swiper-slide">
                    <img src="irina.JPG"/>
                    <p>Irina</p>
                    <p class="yellow">Chief of IT</p>
                </div>
    
                
                <div class="person swiper-slide">
                    <img src="temin.JPG"/>
                    <p>Temin</p>
                    <p class="yellow">Chief of media</p>
                </div>
    
                <div class="person swiper-slide ">
                    <img src="olivia.JPG"/>
                    <p>Olivia</p>
                    <p class="yellow">Chief of finance</p>
                </div>
            
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>

and here is the styling I used:
.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}

.swiper-wrapper {
    justify-content: center;
}

.person {
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    flex-direction: column !important;
    position: relative !important; /* Ensure the pseudo-element is positioned relative to this element */
    padding: 2rem !important ;
    width: auto !important ;
    height: auto !important ;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right:1rem;
}


.person::before {
    content: '' !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0!important;
    right: 0 !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px) !important;/* The semi-transparent white background */
    border-radius: 10px !important; /* Optional: to match your design */
    box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%)!important; /* Optional: shadow effect */
    z-index: -1!important; /* Ensure the pseudo-element is behind the .person content */
}


.swiper-wrapper { justify-content: center; }  - it's already something wrong

You don’t need Javascript to implement a perfectly usable slider/swiper.
A slider/swiper can be as simple as a flexbox styled with overflow: auto, where its child elements are set to a size you specify, and are prohibited from shrinking with flex-shrink: 0. You can easily add scroll snapping as well.
Here is a demo:


body {
  margin: 1em;
  background: #033773;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.person-slider {
  margin: 0 -1em;
  padding: 0 1em 1em;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.person-slider>* {
  width: 200px;
  background: #032144;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

.person-slider img {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.person-slider p {
  margin: 0;
}

.person-slider p:last-child {
  color: #e5cd38;
}
<h2>Meet the Team</h2>

<div class="person-slider">
  
  <div>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/300"/>
      <p>Ioana</p>
      <p>President</p>
  </div>

  <div>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/301"/>
      <p>Iarina</p>
      <p>Vice-President</p>
  </div>

  <div>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/302"/>
      <p>Irina</p>
      <p>IT Manager</p>
  </div>

  <div>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/303"/>
      <p>Temin</p>
      <p>Media Manager</p>
  </div>

  <div>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/304"/>
      <p>Olivia</p>
      <p>Finance Manager</p>
  </div>
            
  <div>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/305"/>
      <p>Issac</p>
      <p>Marketing Manager</p>
  </div>
            
  <div>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/306"/>
      <p>Martha</p>
      <p>Public Relations</p>
  </div>
            
  <div>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/307"/>
      <p>Daphne</p>
      <p>Business Analyst</p>
  </div>
            
  <div>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/308"/>
      <p>Kenneth</p>
      <p>Chief Accountant</p>
  </div>
            
  <div>
      <img src="http://picsum.photos/309"/>
      <p>Yousef</p>
      <p>Programmer</p>
  </div>
            
</div>



